# /when I write this code(here I need to develop a utility with flags)it works so that at the end of the line(created text file)the $ symbol is written

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>           

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    FILE *fp;
    char ch; 
    int count = 1;

    if((fp=fopen(argv[1], "r"))==NULL) {
        printf("Can't open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while((ch=getc(fp))!=EOF) {
        if (ch == '\n') {
            printf("$\n%d.", count);
            count++;
        } else
            printf("%c", ch);
    }  
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

//when I write this code (here I need to develop a utility with flags) it works so that at the end of the line (created text file) the $ symbol is written, but when I try to write it through the switch, nothing happens

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>    

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    (void)argc; 
    int count = 1; 
    int ch; 
    FILE *fp; 
    if((fp=fopen(argv[1], "r"))==NULL) { 
        printf("Can't open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    } 
    while((ch=getc(fp))!=EOF) { 
        switch (ch)
        {
            case 'e' :
                if (ch == '\n') {
                    printf("$\n%d.", count);
                    count++;
                    break;
                }

        }
        fclose(fp);
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `switch (ch) { case 'e' : if (ch == '\n') {....` Here, `ch` can't be `'e'` and `\n` at the same time.

Comment: Note that [`getc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an **`int`**. This is rather important when comparing it to the `int` value `EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what the significance of `'e'` is. The case statement should be for the newline character.

To prevent [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior), avoid passing `fopen` the value `NULL` by checking the argument count of the program. Print errors to the correct stream.

`fclose(fp);` should be moved outside of the body of the `while` loop.

This should work, with minimal changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int count = 1;
    int ch;
    FILE *fp;
    if (argc < 2 || (fp=fopen(argv[1], "r"))==NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while((ch=getc(fp))!=EOF) {
        switch (ch)
        {
            case '\n' :
                    printf("$\n%d.", count);
                    count++;
                    break;
            default:
                    putchar(ch);
                    break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Note, this fails to print a number before the first line, and the second line is labelled `1`. You may want to initialize count to `2`, and simply print `"1."` before the loop, but this will behave strangely with empty files. A more thorough solution may be required.